# Python3 multiple equal sign in the same line

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7

There is a function in the python2 code that I am re-writing into python3

```
def abc(self, id):

    if not isinstance(id, int):

        id = int(id)

    mask = self.programs['ID'] == id
    assert sum(mask) > 0

    name = self.programs[mask]['name'].values[0]
```

"id" here is a panda series where the index is strings and the column is int like the following

```
data = np.array(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5'])
  
# providing an index
ser = pd.Series(data, index =['a', 'b', 'c'])
print(ser)
```

self.programs['ID'] is a dataframe column where there is one row with integer data like '1'

```
import pandas as pd
  
# initialize list of lists
data = [[1, 'abc']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'name'])
```

I am really confused with the line "mask = self.programs['ID'] == id \ assert sum(mask) > 0". Could someone enlighten?

Comment: `mask = self.programs['ID'] == id` would be easier to read if you add the implicit parentheses : `mask = (self.programs['ID'] == id)`

Comment: and the assertion would be better as `assert np.any(mask)`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `mask = self.programs['ID'] == id` would return a series of boolean values, whether thoses 'ID' values are equal to id or not.

Then `assert sum(mask) > 0` sums up the boolean series. Note that, bool True can be treated as 1 in python and 0 for False. So this asserts that, there is at least one case where programs['ID'] column has a value equal to id.